# Should interactions to an external api be a model or a controller action?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Currently building an API that pulls data from another API.

I'm just a little unsure about how I should represent some data considering the whole skinny/fat model/controller argument and I haven't been able to find a clear answer so I was hoping for a discussion on this here.

As Models represent interactions with data it feels like my calls be mapped into a model using something like [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) or Jenssengers ["Laravel Model"](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-model).

As currently I have actions in my controller that send send requests, but it feels like this is a bit too much responsibility for a controller.

So I just wanted some opinions on where I should place this logic in regards to a Laravel project!

Thanks

EDIT:

From further research it looks like the repository design pattern may be a possible solution!

[Repositories Simplified](https://laracasts.com/lessons/repositories-simplified)

[Using Repository Pattern In Laravel 5](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/)

Answer (score 3):

Neither method is particularly a great solution. Really, a Controller is responsible for handling the HTTP requests and your models are representations of your business domain. So where does third-party data fit into this?

Well, the data itself should probably be represented by a model. However, the method of getting the data from the third party provider should really be delegated to a service provider that you can then easily switch out to work with different apis and thus decoupling yourself from a single provider (easiest example would be payment gateways, having all of your logic hard coded in your Controller for a Paypal integration would make it extremely difficult to then later add a second payment option).

Take the following example; let's say you have an application that provides a user with the latest results for their favourite football teams.

Your application could have the following endpoints:

```
/team/{team}/players
/team/{team}/fixtures
/team/{team}/results
```

These could map to the following controller methods:

```
PlayerController@getPlayersInTeam($team);
FixturesController@getFixturesForTeam($team);
ResultsController@getLatestResultsForTeam($team);
```

Notice there are three different controllers, rather than one single controller. This way you can assign a controller to the *type* of model you're expecting to return to the user.

Now obviously, you shouldn't do your API calls within each controller. But, why would you then do it within your model? The term 'Skinny controllers, fat models' is such an anti-pattern that it really does a lot more harm than good.

Why not use a service that is solely responsible for getting data from the API for your models?

```
interface FootballTeamData
{
    public function getPlayersInTeam(Team $team);
    public function getTeamFixtures(Team $team);
    public function getTeamResults(Team $team);
}
```

Now, you can implement this contract and easily switch the way that you get your data from third parties without having to touch your models - which is your business domain, and therefore shouldn't be so highly coupled with the third party API.

You're also now benefiting from skinny controllers, **and** skinny models. There's no reason why a class can't exist that has just a few lines of code, neither should be fat.

Good luck!